# Implement Foldl function in Javascript

Tags: javascript, recursion, functional-programming, fold

I'm trying to write a function that implements foldl in JavaScript. I'm trying to use recursion in the function but not being able to implement it.

```js
var foldl = function(f, acc, array) {
  if (array.length == 0) {
    return acc;
  } else {
    return f(array[0], foldl(f, acc, array.slice(-1)));
  }
}
console.log(foldl(function(x, y) {
  return x + y
}, 0, [1, 2, 3]));
```

```
console.log(foldl(function(x,y){return x+y}, 0, [1,2,3]));
```

**Error Message**..

```
 RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your challenge, as mentioned above, is that you're returning an array of the last element. And you're always returning an array of the last element.

What is missing from the answers above is that they're only good for folding to the right.
For the right case, you can just use `.slice(1)`, and that will pull everything after the head.
For the fold left case, you need to specify how far you need to go `.slice(0, arr.length - 1)`.

```
const foldr = (f, acc, arr) => {
  if (!arr.length) {
    return acc;
  } else {
    const head = arr[0];
    const tail = arr.slice(1);
    return foldr(f, f(acc, head), tail);
  }
};

foldr((x, y) => x + y, 0, [1, 2, 3])// 6

const foldl = (f, acc, arr) => {
  if (!arr.length) {
    return acc;
  } else {
    const head = arr[arr.length - 1];
    const tail = arr.slice(0, arr.length - 1);
    return foldl(f, f(acc, head), tail);
  }
};

foldl((x, y) => x + y, 0, [3, 2, 1]); // 6
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation between foldl and foldr cases!!! There was a gap in my knowledge.

Comment: `foldr` is right-associative, meaning that the folding function is called on the result of the recursive call, i.e. `return f(head, foldr(f, acc, tail))`. `foldl` is left-associative, meaning that the head of the list is computed first. Usually the order of parameters in `f` change to reflect that.

Comment: Great answer, it helps understand the difference. But having `foldr` i would right `foldl` as `foldl = (f, acc, arr) => foldr(f, acc, [...arr].reverse())`

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
array.slice(-1)
```

should be:

```
array.slice(1)
```

`slice(-1)` returns the array containing the last element. As you're using the first element of the array, you want the array without that element instead. `slice(1)` will return the array without the first element.

Comment: But making Slice(-1) will make the code run according to Foldr logic right?

Answer (score 0):

`slice(-1)` return only the last element. If you want to recurse over the array, use `slice(1)` instead, which will return all elements except the first:

```js
var foldl = function(f, acc, array) {
  if (array.length == 0) {
    return acc;
  } else {
    return f(array[0], foldl(f, acc, array.slice(1)));
  }
}
console.log(foldl(function(x, y) {
  return x + y
}, 0, [1, 2, 3]));
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that `foldl` and `foldr` can *both* be implemented in a way that iterates thru the input list in first-to-rest (left-to-right) order. Awkward negative indexes or calculating precise `slice` positions are not needed.

```js
const Empty =
  Symbol ()

const foldl = (f, acc, [ x = Empty, ...xs ]) =>
  x === Empty
    ? acc
    : foldl (f, f (acc, x), xs)

const foldr = (f, acc, [ x = Empty, ...xs ]) =>
  x === Empty
    ? acc
    : f (foldr (f, acc, xs), x)
    
const pair = (a,b) =>
  `(${a} ${b})`

const data =
  [ 1, 2, 3 ]

console.log (foldl (pair, 0, data))
// (((0 1) 2) 3)

console.log (foldr (pair, 0, data))
// (((0 3) 2) 1)
```

You can use `xs[0]` and `xs.slice(1)` if you don't want to use the destructuring assignment

```js
const foldl = (f, acc, xs) =>
  xs.length === 0
    ? acc
    : foldl (f, f (acc, xs[0]), xs.slice (1))

const foldr = (f, acc, xs) =>
  xs.length === 0
    ? acc
    : f (foldr (f, acc, xs.slice (1)), xs [0])
 
const pair = (a,b) =>
  `(${a} ${b})`

const data =
  [ 1, 2, 3 ]

console.log (foldl (pair, 0, data))
// (((0 1) 2) 3)

console.log (foldr (pair, 0, data))
// (((0 3) 2) 1)
```

`...xs` via destructuring assignment used in the first solution and `slice` used in the second solution create intermediate values and could be a performance hit if `xs` is of considerable size. Below, a third solution that avoids this

```js
const foldl = (f, acc, xs, i = 0) =>
  i >= xs.length
    ? acc
    : foldl (f, f (acc, xs[i]), xs, i + 1)

const foldr = (f, acc, xs, i = 0) =>
  i >= xs.length
    ? acc
    : f (foldr (f, acc, xs, i + 1), xs [i])
 
const pair = (a,b) =>
  `(${a} ${b})`

const data =
  [ 1, 2, 3 ]

console.log (foldl (pair, 0, data))
// (((0 1) 2) 3)

console.log (foldr (pair, 0, data))
// (((0 3) 2) 1)
```

Above our `foldl` and `foldr` are almost perfect drop-in replacements for natives `Array.prototype.reduce` and `Array.prototype.reduceRight` respectively. By passing `i` and `xs` to the callback, we get even closer

```js
const foldl = (f, acc, xs, i = 0) =>
  i >= xs.length
    ? acc
    : foldl (f, f (acc, xs[i], i, xs), xs, i + 1)

const foldr = (f, acc, xs, i = 0) =>
  i >= xs.length
    ? acc
    : f (foldr (f, acc, xs, i + 1), xs[i], i, xs)

const pair = (acc, value, i, self) =>
{
  console.log (acc, value, i, self)
  return acc + value
}

console.log (foldl (pair, 'a', [ 'b', 'c', 'd' ]))
// a   b  0  [ b, c, d ]
// ab  c  1  [ b, c, d ]
// abc d  2  [ b, c, d ]
// => abcd

console.log (foldr (pair, 'z', [ 'w', 'x', 'y' ]))
// z   y  2  [ x, y, z ]
// zy  x  1  [ x, y, z ]
// zyx w  0  [ x, y, z ]
// => zyxw
```

And finally, `reduce` and `reduceRight` accept a *context* argument. This is important if the folding function `f` refers to `this`. If you want to support a configurable context in your own folds, it's easy

```js
const foldl = (f, acc, xs, context = null, i = 0) =>
  i >= xs.length
    ? acc
    : foldl ( f
            , f.call (context, acc, xs[i], i, xs)
            , xs
            , context
            , i + 1
            )

const foldr = (f, acc, xs, context = null, i = 0) =>
  i >= xs.length
    ? acc
    : f.call ( context
             , foldr (f, acc, xs, context, i + 1)
             , xs[i]
             , i
             , xs
             )
    
const obj =
  { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 4, e: 5 }

// some function that uses `this` 
const picker = function (acc, key) {
  return  [ ...acc, { [key]: this[key] } ]
}
  
console.log (foldl (picker, [], [ 'b', 'd', 'e' ], obj))
// [ { b: 2 }, { d: 4 }, { e: 5 } ]

console.log (foldr (picker, [], [ 'b', 'd', 'e' ], obj))
// [ { e: 5 }, { d: 4 }, { b: 2 } ]
```

Comment: Right folding isn't a meaningful concept in strictly evaluated languages, because the only thing it gives us in addition is blowing the stack. In Haskell `foldr` can short circuit (among other things), provided it is OK to ignore `acc`. We can use explicit thunks in JS to get similar behavior, however, this requires `foldr` to be in curried form and `acc` to be the last argument of `f`. [See more](https://wiki.haskell.org/Foldr_Foldl_Foldl%27). +1

Comment: @ftor i haven’t had a chance to read that link yet, but `foldr` only yields the same result when `f` is *commutative*. Consider the familiar example `foldl (comp, ...)` vs `foldr (comp, ...)`. I’ll review that link when I get home later ^^

Comment: If only commutativity matters, you can always resort to `flip`, right?

Comment: @ftor, do you mean to ask if `foldr (f, ...)` is the same as `foldl (flip (f), ...)`?